# Number of accepted answers

Tags: support, accepted-answer

Is there a way to find the number of accepted answers you have, other than manually counting each one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use "hasaccepted:1 user:130822" or "isaccepted:1 user:130822" (depending which ones you want) and do the math.
E.g. [Jon Skeet's accepted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isaccepted%3a1%20user%3a22656&page=42&tab=relevance):

The numbers will change soon, but here we go:
I see 41 pages with 50 entries each. One page with 2 entries.
41x50 + 2 = ?

That's only partly "counting" ;-)

Comment: You also get the number of results at the first page (an update perhaps since 2009). E.g., for the link you specified: 
19,418 results

Answer (score 5):

You can use [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/335389/how-close-am-i-to-unsung-hero-badge-including-10-days-requirement) StackExchange Data Explorer query.

> Zero and non-zero accepted count. Self-accepted answers do not count.

Enter User ID, you can also switch between sites:
[image: screen-shot]

---

Hope this helps you.
<sub>Thanks @[durron597](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/200235/durron597) for suggesting in [chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3705788#3705788)</sub>