# Add accepted answers to user page

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, accepted-answer, unaccepted-answer

Given the range of information now available across the tabs of a user's profile page, the outstanding missing list is accepted and unaccepted answers, preferably with datestamps.

I suggest it is added as a sub-tab of `responses`, or `answers`.

This could then be a relevant place to summarise [total accepts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13642/147650), total non-own accepts and any other accept-based counts that are needed to help determine badges.

Comment: Seeing as the whole idea of displaying the accept rates is [in debate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate), I don't see this as a good addition.

Comment: I know you can see current accepted answers a number of ways, but you're not notified except via points changes in reputation which are a little hard to isolate.

Comment: @Oded I'm not referring to your acceptance of your questions, but others acceptance of your answers.

Comment: What about answers to questions that have more than your one answer? What about questions where someone else answer was accepted?

Comment: @Oded I'm really only asking for what is already listed in the reputation tab: the +15 accepts and -15 unaccepts in a separate list with the datestamps.

Comment: I should say I'd expect un/accepting my own answers (which is -/+0 reputation) should also be included. And similarly for CW un/accepteds. In other words all un/accepted of my _answers_, _not_ my _questions_ which is what the "debate" is about.

Answer (score 10):

I won't go and add whole new tab but rather support sorting by accepted answers in the *answers* tab:

> [image]

This way it will be easier to find all your accepted answers.

Note that this is already possible via the search box - just add `isaccepted:1` to the search query and you will get list of [your accepted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:256431%20isaccepted:1). (29 on Stack Overflow right now)

Comment: Nah, searching for `user:me isaccepted:1` gives you that.

Comment: bet some of your votes came from [freehand circle lovers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14581/100-thousand-views-or-more-thousand-comes-below-views#comment28068_14581)

Comment: @Mark true, forgot about that (and added now to my post for sake of others) but still shortcut from the profile page would be nice.

Comment: @ajax might be - learned to use them in my early days here. :)