# Add "Accepted answer" sub-tab to the "Answers" tab

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, accepted-answer, tabs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add accepted answers to user page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142604/add-accepted-answers-to-user-page)

There is an answers tab in stackoverflow user page where users can track their answers. Currently 3 sorting options are there.

[image: Answers Tab]

Is there any chance for another tab as `Accepted` so that users can track on their **accepted answers** like the image below;

[image: Suggested Answers Tab]

It may be sorted newest first. The tab may display answers posted by the user for questions asked by other users and the same user as well.

*This is a small suggestion from my part as a community member.*

Comment: To make sure people vote on the correct thing: Are you asking for the tab to display answers that the user has accepted, or answers the user has submitted that were accepted by another person?

Comment: both. all accepted answers even if the question is asked by the same user.

Comment: Well those are *sorters* up there, not search criteria. This was also [already suggested elsewhere](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142604/add-accepted-answers-to-user-page).

Comment: @animuson its in the answer and I am asking this as a question.

Comment: @blasteralfred: The question itself covers adding accepted answers to the profile in general, which covers the suggestion as well. We don't need separate feature requests for every possible solution to one problem.