# How to count accepted answers for questions not asked by ourself

Tags: support, accepted-answer

I have answered for questions in SO (some are asked by me) and in that, some answers are accepted with +1s, some are accepted with no +1s, and some are not accepted. Is there any way I can count or track on **accepted answers I posted** which are **not for questions I asked**?

Note: I know how to track accepted answers using **isaccepted:1 user:484082**

Comment: hasaccepted:1 user:484082 (See all available options [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=)).

Comment: i think this is pulling out everything :(

Comment: True, my bad. Looks like Jon tip is the best for now, don't think there is any built-in way to find such data.

Comment: If you are familiar with SQL, you could use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) to find this information.  That database is refreshed once every few months (the most current data in there for Stack Overflow right now is June 26th).

Answer (score 9):

One simple option for doing it manually every so often: go to https://stackoverflow.com/reputation and count the lines containing `(15)` or `[15]` - you wouldn't get 15 rep for anything other than an accepted answer to a non-self-asked question.

(I'm not entirely sure of the difference between the bracket types at the moment. Looking at that now...)

Comment: Don't see any [15] in my data. Good tip though! :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [data.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) and query the data dump.

For your convenience, I've built [a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/77239/87771/my-accepted-answers) that *I believe* will find the ID's of your accepted answers.

Comment: Only problem is that the data there is not live.

Comment: It's close enough, really. If that's a really big deal you can always look on your profile page and add in the ones that aren't there. They'll be few, from the last 4 weeks or less.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Recycled/Included/Reused [Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/260745/260388)</sup>

(You can use [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/335389/how-close-am-i-to-unsung-hero-badge-including-10-days-requirement) StackExchange Data Explorer query.

> Zero and non-zero accepted count. Self-accepted answers do not count.

Enter User ID, you can also switch between sites:
[image: screen-shot]

---

Hope this helps you.
<sub>Thanks @[durron597](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/200235/durron597) for suggesting in [chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3705788#3705788)</sub>