# How to get the number of accepted answers except the self-accepted posts?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

I found a way in [Number of accepted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13642/number-of-accepted-answers).
But it counts all the answers, including self-accepted answeres to your own questions.

So, is there a way to get the number of accepted answers except the self-accepted?

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do this using the current search options. However, you may write a query on [StackExchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) to get this number.

Comment: One way to do that would be opening [`/reputation`](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation) and looking for `(15)` and `[15]`

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ could you describe this way in a greater detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What NullUserException means is this:

[image]

Go to https://stackoverflow.com/reputation, Ctrl+F for `(15)` and see how many results you get. Apparently I have 280 accepted answers.